# Load new web page on successful password check

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, jboss7.x, el

I am trying to write some 'Expression language' code. At the moment, under (1) below the greetController.greet method is called and this returns a string if the user name and password matches. What I want to do is instead load another webpage if the string returned is a certain value. Please can someone advise how this could be done

Thanks in advance

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">

<ui:composition template="template.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="content">
        <h:messages />
        <h:form id="greetForm">
            <h:panelGrid columns="3">
                <h:outputLabel for="username">Enter username:</h:outputLabel>
                <h:inputText id="username"
                    value="#{greetController.username}" />
                <br />
                <h:outputLabel for="password">Enter password:</h:outputLabel>
                <h:inputText id="password"
                    value="#{greetController.password}" />
                <h:message for="username" />
            </h:panelGrid>
            <h:commandButton id="greet" value="Login"
                **action="#{greetController.greet}" />** //(1)
        </h:form>
        **<h:outputText value="#{greetController.greeting}"** //(2)
            rendered="#{not empty greetController.greeting}" />
        <br />
        <h:link outcome="/create.xhtml" value="Add a new user" />
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
</html>
```

Comment: on `success` do you want to open in `New tab` in browser?

Answer (score 1):

My answer assumes this login form is in **/app/login.xhtml**, and you want to load another webpage (say **/app/home.xhtml**) if the string returned is a value (say **success**):

**For JSF2**

If you are using JSF2, you can simply return the URL of next page from your bean

```
public String login()
{
   // check user password...
   return "/app/home.xhtml"
   // this will work without faces-config.xml entry using JSF2
}
```

**For JSF1 or JSF2**

Just add this entry to your faces-config.xml file.

```
    <navigation-rule>
        <from-view-id>/app/login.xhtml</from-view-id>
        <navigation-case>
            <from-outcome>success</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>/app/home.xhtml</to-view-id>
        </navigation-case>
    </navigation-rule>
```

**More Info**
Your question is very basic. I recommend to follow a beginner level tutorial on JSF. For example: http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/jsf-2-0-tutorials/

Comment: I guess OP may want to open in New tab on Success

Comment: No need to open in new tab guys. Thanks Ammar. I will give it a try and let you know how it goes